# calling a command from script and maintain styling

Tags: bash, ls

I am calling a command from a script running on Linux. In this case, `ls` to list directory contents.

When I call `ls` from the script, I do a simple `while` loop to read the output line by line.

I then print the line using `echo` and double quotes e.g. `echo "$line"`.
It does echo out each line but it loses all styling (colours).

How would I maintain the styling while still being able to process the lines my self?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two problems here. First of all, what you are doing is absolutely the wrong way to process the files in a directory and will break if your file names contain newlines or other strangeness. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for more.

That said, the colors of `ls` are optional. In many Linux distributions, the command `ls` is actually aliased to `ls --color=tty` which enables colors when `ls` is printing to a tty (as opposed to a `while` loop, for example). However, aliases are not enabled in scripts usually so when you run `ls` from your script, you're just running normal `ls` with no colors.

So, the first ugly workaround would be to call `ls --color=always`. That will let you echo with colors. However, this is almost certainly a bad idea as I mentioned in the first paragraph. For one thing, if you just want to print each line out, why don't you just run `ls` and forget the `while` loop?

If you do need to process the files for some other reason and still need to use `ls` as well, use globbing to get the list of files and then run `ls` on each of them manually:

```
for file in *; do
    ls -d --color=always -- "$file"
done
```

That will not break on weird file names and will still show you the colors as you requested.

Comment: I shall apply this into my special filtering, should not be too difficult, thank you for the insight, it keeps the colours but sadly removes the lines but im sure I could hack it in (unless you have any suggestions?)